# Spaces between sections and subsections on moderncv

Tags: spacing, moderncv

I have been trying to get spaces included between sections and subsection as it looks so narrowed down (`moderncv`). Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}

% moderncv themes
\moderncvtheme[blue]{casual}                 % optional argument are 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'red', 'green', 'grey' and 'roman' (for roman fonts, instead of sans serif fonts)
%\moderncvtheme[green]{classic}                % idem

% character encoding
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}         
         % replace by the encoding you are using
\newcommand{\localtextbulletone}{\textcolor{color1}{$\vcenter{\hbox{\tiny$\bullet$}}$}}%Changes Item List bullet size and color
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{\localtextbulletone}%Sets the new bullet type



% adjust the page margins
\usepackage[scale=0.8]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}



\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm}                      % if you want to change the width of the column with the dates
%\AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\maketitlenamewidth}{6cm}}  % only for the classic theme, if you want to change the width of your name placeholder (to leave more space for your address details
%\AtBeginDocument{\recomputelengths}                     % required when changes are made to page layout lengths
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{\rmdefault} %?ndert die schriftart


\begin{document}



\maketitle


\section{Zu meiner Person}
\cvline{Geboren}{am 07.06.1983 in Berlin}
\cvline{Familienstand}{ledig}

\section{Studium}


\subsection{Masterstudium 'Volkswirtschaftslehre'}
\cvline{09/2009 - 09/11}{\textbf{Birkbeck, University of London, UK, }\newline \emph{Schwerpunkte: Wachstums?konomie, Makroökonometrie und Statistik}}


\subsection{Masterthesis:}
\cvline{Titel}{\emph{Mugabe's Monetized Budget Deficit - The Epitome of Zimbabwe's Economic Tragedy?-An Investigation into the Causes of Zimbabwe's Hyperinflation and the Options
for its Monetary Regime.}}
\cvline{Betreuer}{Prof. Ron Smith and Prof. John Driffle}

\subsection{Bachelorstudium 'Volkswirtschaftslehre \& Finanzen'}
\cvline{09/2006 - 07/09}{\textbf{London Metropolitan Business School, UK,}\emph{ (Note: 1,0)}}
\subsection{Bachelorthesis, durchgef?hrt als zwei Teilprojekte:}
\cvline{1st. Thesis}{\emph{The Yuan: America's Foreign Boogeyman? An Investigation into the Chinese Exchange Rate Regime. (Note: 1,0)}}
\cvline{2nd.Thesis}{\emph{Is Outsourcing really as bad as its critics allege?  (Note: 1,0)}}
\cvline{Betreuer}{Prof. Steven Smith \& Prof. Craig Duckworth}

\section{Beruflicher Werdegang}
\cvline{02/2012 - 04/12}{\textbf{Schneider Trading Associates, London, UK}\newline 
{\empty}{Trading Floor Training Programme: Proprietary Trading}}
```

Answer (score 9):

The `moderncv` style file (on my system this file can be found in `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/moderncv/moderncvstylecasual.sty`) redefines the `\section` command. Copy that `\RenewDocumentCommand` part to the preamble of your `.tex` file and put `\makeatletter` above it and `\makeatother` below it, as shown here:

```
% Increase the vertical spacing between the sections
\makeatletter
\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{sm}{%
  \par\addvspace{1cm}%
  \phantomsection{}% reset the anchor for hyperrefs
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#2}%
  \parbox[t]{\hintscolumnwidth}{\strut\raggedleft\raisebox{\baseletterheight}{\color{color1}\rule{\hintscolumnwidth}{0.95ex}}}%
  \hspace{\separatorcolumnwidth}%
  \parbox[t]{\maincolumnwidth}{\strut\sectionstyle{#2}}%
  \par\nobreak\addvspace{1ex}\@afterheading}% to avoid a pagebreak after the heading
\makeatother
```

The actual change in vertical space is in the line (the default was `2.5ex`):

```
\par\addvspace{1cm}%
```